# Finding irreducible representations of the following group using GAP

Tags: representation-theory, math-software, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, gap

Given the following group of order 24, $$ G = \langle a,b \mid a^2=b^3=(abab^2)^2=1\rangle$$  how can one find (all) the irreducible representations using GAP? Since I have not installed GAP yet, I would like to use the SAGE interface to GAP. If you give me the SAGE code for such presentation, I will be able to compute for others too.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the size of the $G$?

Comment: @Unknown: I wrote the code for the $G$ in GAP. Moreover I found a link that you can find the I.R. of the $G$. Wanna that or you want a complete code?

Comment: The order of the group is 24. Thanks for asking. I will include it in the question. @sasha, thank you for the editing.

Comment: @BabakS., thank you very much. Yes, I would like to see the code you wrote. Can I also run it on my online sage notebook account?

Comment: I don't know Sage as I am familiar to the GAP. But, I add my attempt and wait to see other codes. Thanks ;-)

Comment: That will be great help, @BabakS. Please proceed in posting.

Answer (score 6):

I think the main body of the program contains the following codes:

> f:=FreeGroup(2);;
>
> a:=f.1;; b:=f.2;;
>
> G:=f/[a^2,b^(3),(a*b*a*b^(2))^2];;

another codes which may help us will be:

> e:=Elements(s);
>
> Size(s);
>
> IsSolvable(s);

Now follow this link to find the exact willing: [Irreducible Representations.](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/repsn/doc/chap2.html)

Comment: Thanks @Babak S., I am experimenting with SAGE and I think I can use the commnad $$ print gap.eval(''the gap code'')  $$ to translate codes in GAP to SAGE.

Comment: @Herband: It is yours now. :-) Take it and see if it is work or not?

Comment: Thank you. Let me see what I can do. I will post an answer if I get it right.

Comment: Nice!!!!! + 1 and $\;$ 8-)

Comment: hehehehehe! ;-)  (Only when driving!)